# Passing logged in user credentials to Powershell cmdlet

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Service running (service is running as "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM") on Windows 2012 Server. This service needs to get a list of VMs from a remote machine. It executes cmdlet equivalent of "get-vm -ComputerSystem RemoteServer1". Currently logged in user is 'Administrator' who has access to call get-vm on the remote machine. However, "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" does not have permission to call get-vm on the remote machine. Below is the code.

```
PowerShell psStopVM = PowerShell.Create();
psStopVM.AddCommand("Stop-VM");
psStopVM.AddParameter("Name", vmName);
psStopVM.AddParameter("ComputerName", VMHost);
psStopVM.AddParameter("Force", true);

psStopVM.Invoke(); //exception occurs here
```

When I run this code, I get the following error.
Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualizationOperationFailedException: You do not have permission to perform the operation. Contact your administrator if you believe you should have permission to perform this operation. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

How can I pass the credentials of logged in user (Administrator) in the C# code such that I can successfully call get-vm cmdlet from C# Code?

Comment: You have to use [credentials](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849815.aspx), here is [one example](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/)

Comment: Brock, I don't want to be prompted for password. I want to pass the credentials of currently logged in user seamlessly.

Comment: You don't mention this, but is there a reason not to run the service as the (or an) Administrator?

Comment: Is this an Active Directory domain or not?

Comment: Tim - I dont think of there is any reason. But I dont want to run it as Administrator as it may cause other unrelated issues (its a big service).
Brock - this system can be added to a domain by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use **Invoke-Command** and create an ad hoc session with admin creds to invoke you command with sufficient privileges or, if you need to run more than one command, you can create a remote runspace with admin credentials and execute your commands in that runspace. This will require WinRM service configured and running.

You other option, and I would go that route, is to run the service under identity of the admin user or a dedicated account with sufficient privileges instead of NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. This way you do not store your admin creds insecurely with your code, not naming other consequences of hard-coding creds.